# Не запускается активити через сервис

Tags: activity, android, java, service

Есть активити (1). В onPause создаётся сервис (s), который по истечению некоторого времени запускает другую активити (2). В этой активити (2) в onCreate прописано пробуждение экрана, снятие блокировки, запуск активити (1) и сразу финиш.

(а) Блокируем экран. Переход в onPause(), запускаем сервис, проходит время, экран загорается, мы видим нужную активити. Всё работает.

---

Всё работает исправно. Но если:

(б) свернуть приложение (аппаратной кнопкой "назад"), заблокировать экран - всё ещё работает.

(в) после пункта (б) попробовать снова проделать пункт (а), то активити (2) уже не запустится. По логам видно, что параметры передаются верно, всё всегда одинаково, но почему то при действиях (б-в), startActivity просто не запускает новую активити (2).

Проблема крутится вокруг этой самой андроидовской кнопки "назад". Потому что если свернуть кнопкой "домой" всё работает это раз. Если имея проблему ещё раз нажать кнопку "назад" то потом всё снова будет работать. Вот так вот.

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему. Это стандартное (но какое то странное) поведение для андроида. Исправил проблему прописав в манифесте проблемной активити (2) android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Answer (score 0):

Можно также через флаги:

```
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 startActivity(i);
```